# Looping and Copy Data to a new sheet

Tags: vba, excel

This is my first post, but I have an excel workbook with multiple tabs formatted like this:

[image: current screenshot]

I'm learning vba but don't know the excel functions well enough yet to loop through the rows and copy the data reformatted to a new sheet into this format:

[image: expected result]

Specifically I think i need to
- Initialize the range of worksheets

- loop through them
- store column headers for b through G into a variable so when the x is found it can be concatenated or copied over
- handle the blank spaces so that the last value is used for each one

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If you are not familiar with VBA it will be difficult to get any answers here because practically we have to write the code for you. I recommend that you study a bit online and learn basics and come up with a simple code and then we help you to better it and do whatever you want to do

Comment: Definitely, I know some vba and can definitely understand what has been provided but a starting point was largely what i was looking for. I'm working to learn in parallel with getting a timely way to organize this data made for easy viewing but not quite handy for any kind of analysis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will do what you expect:

```
Sub foo()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
'declare and set your worksheet, amend as required
Dim wsResult As Worksheet: Set wsResult = Sheets("Sheet2")
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
'get the last row with data on Column J

For i = 2 To LastRow
    NextRow = wsResult.Cells(wsResult.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    ws.Range("H" & i & ":J" & i).Copy Destination:=wsResult.Range("D" & NextRow)
    wsResult.Range("A" & NextRow).Value = "Title"
    If ws.Cells(i, 1) <> "" Then 'if GroupID is not empty
        wsResult.Range("B" & NextRow).Value = ws.Cells(i, 1) 'grab that GroupID
    Else
        x = i
        Do While Trim(ws.Cells(x, 1)) = ""
            x = x - 1
            Group = ws.Cells(x, 1) 'get the GroupID of the Row above
        Loop
        wsResult.Range("B" & NextRow).Value = Group
    End If

    For y = 2 To 7
        If ws.Cells(i, y) <> "" Then
            Level = ws.Cells(1, y).Value
            Exit For
        End If
    Next y
    wsResult.Cells(NextRow, 3) = Level
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked great. There are cases in my dataset that the level is not marked by an x and it creates blanks in column b for the group but I will try to loop through the multiple sheets and address the blanks when no x is found. Thanks for the valuable input!

Comment: I've updated my answer so instead of looking for an x, it will check to see which cell is not empty, thus any symbol should work now... :)

Comment: Thanks, i found one other thing in the data set where the groupid is blank there is actually a trailing space in some cells which throws off the not empty "" comparison to grab groupids. I'm trying out the trim function to see if it sorts that out.

Comment: @Oliver I've updated the answer to trim the contents of the cell before doing the comparison...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub BuildTable()
    Dim data(), i As Integer, j As Integer

    data = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:J5").Value

    For i = 1 To UBound(data)
        With Worksheets("Sheet2")
            .Range("A" & i) = "Title"
            .Range("D" & i) = data(i, 8)
            .Range("E" & i) = data(i, 9)
            .Range("F" & i) = data(i, 10)

            If i > 1 Then
                .Range("B" & i) = IIf(data(i, 1) <> "", data(i, 1), .Range("B" & i - 1))
            Else
                .Range("B" & i) = data(i, 1)
            End If

            For j = 2 To 7
                If data(i, j) = "x" Then
                    .Range("C" & i) = "Level" & j - 1
                End If
            Next j

        End With
    Next i 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Power Query** Excel 2010+ you can download and activate easily or by default in 2016 version. There you can transform your data and put it as a table or a pivot table:

[image]

Comment: I had not seen power query before i'll check it out as well. It looks like a solid tool to have on hand.

Comment: It is absolutely, this is the answer of Microsoft Office for Big Data and Business Intelligence.